# React, onMouseOver event trigger all items in list instead of one

Tags: reactjs

I have problem with hovering buttons in list of li's. After hovering one li item button shows in every li item. Link to codepen below the piece of code.

```
const ItemView = (props) => {
return <li 
onMouseOver={() => props.onMouseOver()}
onMouseMove={() => props.onMouseOver()}
onMouseLeave={() => props.onMouseLeave()}
>
    <div className="item__row">
        <h5>{props.name}</h5>
        <h6>Age: {props.age}</h6>
        <p>{props.strenght}/100</p>


    {props.isHover ? props.children[0] : null}


    </div>
    {props.children[1]}
</li>
```

}

Codepen: https://codepen.io/dominik3246/pen/QqKzzp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an array of element which keeps track of which particular element was hovered. So take `isHover` state variable as an array like

```
constructor(){
  ...
  this.state ={
  ...
  isHover: [false, false, false, false, false],
  ...
  }
}
```

Then make your mouseOver function to return a function containing scope of the index of the item like this

```
mouseOver(i) {
    return () => {
      if (this.state.isHover[i] === true) {
        return this.state;
      }
      let isHover = [...this.state.isHover]
      isHover[i] = true;
      this.setState({ ...this.state, isHover });
    }
  }
```

And then to pass `isHover` and `mouseOver` prop to your `ItemView` like this

```
{this.state.data.map((d, i) => {
          return (
            <ItemView
              key={d.id}
              name={d.name}
              strenght={d.strenght}
              age={d.age}
              onMouseOver={this.mouseOver(i)}
              onMouseLeave={this.mouseExit}
              isHover={this.state.isHover[i]}
            >
            ...
```

Here is the working example of your code : [Link of example](https://codesandbox.io/s/2mp38x8zr)

Comment: thats great, but what if I don't know how much data I will receive? I mean like fetching data, where sometimes i can receive 5 data items, and sometimes 100. Here, unfortunately, you need to set manually isHover state

Comment: @dominik Thats because you are keeping track of hovering of each child element in parent therefore you have to keep an array to track which child element was hovered.
An other approach would be to move the hover handler function to child element so each child is responsible to handle its own hovering logic. In that case you would  just have to render the children without keeping track of which children was hovered.